# localStorage Overwritten/ and innerHTML fail

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

On the 14th and 28th line, it's not changing the text of the label tag and on the recorForm or loginSetup, data is overwritten.
 I tried loop with `.key`, but it outputed the wrong stored results and I'm not sure what I did wrong.
 so I'm leaving it at this.
 What I want to know is why the innHTML of the label won't change.(I assume it's due to loading)

```
window.onload = alert('Window Loaded');

    function recordForm() {
      var userMail = document.getElementById('email').value;
      var userPass = document.getElementById('password').value;
      var confirm = document.getElementById('confirmation').value;
      var text = document.getElemetsByClassName('errorText');

      //Check that the email is not taken and confirm validation
      if ((userPass === confirm)) {
        localStorage.setItem('emailz', userMail.value);
        localStorage.setItem('passwordz', userPass.value);
      } else {
        text.innerHTML = 'Password does not match!'; //line 14
      }
    }

    function loginSetup() {
      var mail = localStorage.getItem('emailz');
      var pass = localStorage.getItem('passwordz');
      var mailInput = document.getElementById('logEmail').value;
      var passInput = document.getElementById('logPassword').value;

      if ((mailInput === mail) && (passInput === pass)) {
        alert(mail);
        alert(pass); 
        } else {
              text.innerHTML = 'Invalid login'; //line 28
        alert('no dice');
        alert(mail);
        alert(pass);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please post the relevant HTML as well. Also, change all of your `alert` lines to `console.log`, which won't block the UI and cause any side-effects.

Comment: userMail and userPass have no value while writing them into localStorage, since those are .value already.

Comment: Open the Console in your developer tools. Read the error messages. You've misspelt function names for a start.

Answer (score 1):

You should try to store userMail.value and userPass.value. Both yet are already the values:

```
var userMail = document.getElementById('email').value; //Those are values already
var userPass = document.getElementById('password').value; //Those are values already

if ((userPass === confirm)) {
        localStorage.setItem('emailz', userMail); //Remove the .value
        localStorage.setItem('passwordz', userPass); //Remove the .value
}
```

Also getEleme**n**tsByClassName returns a collection, thus you want to select the first item of it (assumably):

```
var text = document.getElemetsByClassName('errorText'); //Misstyped and no index.. wont work

var text = document.getElementsByClassName('errorText')[0]; //Should work
var text = document.querySelector('.errorText'); //Would prefer that one
```

At last in the function loginSetup() you have to redefine text:

```
var text = document.querySelector('.errorText');
```

Comment: Why does the text change back and forth? First, it was set blank, the code was called, it changed, but then it changed back.

Comment: I can hardly tell since a man merely shares a small part of the actual code and function calls.